# How to assign the python interpreter spark worker used?

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

### How to assign the python interpreter spark worker used?

i try several method like:
1) set env Vars

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/python_path/bin/python
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/python_path/bin/python
```

not work. i'm sure PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON PYSPARK_PYTHON env set success use:

```
env | grep PYSPARK_PYTHON
```

i want to pyspark use

```
 /python_path/bin/python
```

as the starting python interpreter

but worker start use the :

```
python -m deamon
```

i don't want to link default python to /python_path/bin/python in the fact that 
this may affect other devs, bcz default python and /python_path/bin/python is not same version, and both in production use.

Also set spark-env.sh not works:

spark.pyspark.driver.python=/python_path/bin/python
spark.pyspark.python=/python_path/bin/python

when start driver some warning logs like:

> conf/spark-env.sh: line 63:
>   spark.pyspark.driver.python=/python_path/bin/python: No such file or directory 
>   conf/spark-env.sh: line 64:
>   spark.pyspark.python=/python_path/bin/python: No such file or directory

Comment: `spark.pyspark.driver.python` and `spark.pyspark.python` should be set in `spark-defaults.conf`. The equivalent in `spark-env.sh` is `export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/python_path/bin/python`, `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/python_path/bin/python`. Check both files to make sure these options don't get overwritten.

Comment: @MaFF thanks for ur remind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Check permissions on your python directory. Maybe Spark doesn't have correct permissions. Try to do: `sudo chmod -R 777  /python_path/bin/python`

2) Spark [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables) says:

> Property spark.pyspark.python take precedence if it is set.

So try also set `spark.pyspark.python` in `conf/spark-defaults.conf`.

3) Also if you use cluster with more then one node you need to check if Python is installed in a correct directory on each node because you don't know where workers will be started.

4) Spark will use the first Python interpreter available on your system PATH, so like workaround you can set the path to your python in PYTHON variable.

Comment: thanks, very specific, i check you instruction one by one right now.

Comment: Has it helped you?

Comment: thanks, very helpful, but  it's not works as my case, my case is spark in cluster mode,  the master node and worker have different  python_path, i do as your instructs on all nodes,  every time i run a python task, the worker node always start with the default python not my setting spark.pyspark.driver.python.